# jQuery .add method

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, addition

I'm writing a simple jQuery plugin that displays images with a specific class in the center of the screen (when clicked, full-sized) with a gray overlay around the image. When we click on the overlay it disappears. Now I use this piece of code:

```
$("#overlay").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 500, function(){
            $(this).css({
                display: "none"
            });
        });

        $("#imgcontainer").animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 500, function(){
            $(this).css({
                display: "none"
            });

        });

    });
```

imgcontainer holds our image. I was trying to use this easier code, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#overlay").click(function(){
        $(this).add("#imgcontainer").animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 500, function(){
            $(this).css({
                display: "none"
            });
        });
    });
```

Why it doesn't work?

**UPDATE:**
Correct code:

```
$("#overlay").click(function(){
        $("#imgcontainer").add(this).fadeOut();
    });
```

Thanks a lot for replies. This behavior (bug?) is very surprising indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using v1.4.x, because of [issue #7853](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7853) I just raised in their bug tracker earlier today (what timing!). You can fix it by changing this:

```
$(this).add("#imgcontainer").animate(...
```

to

```
$(this).add($("#imgcontainer")).animate(...
```

**Update**: Here's a better (more efficient) way, as Nick pointed out below:

```
$("#imgcontainer").add(this).animate(...
```

(See also his note about `fadeOut`.)

In jQuery 1.3.2 and earlier, it would have worked as you expected. I don't know whether the 1.4.x thing is a bug or an intentional incompatible change.

<s>**Question though**: Why not just fade out the container? If it contains the image, that should fade the image too, shouldn't it? As in [this example](http://jsbin.com/azuwa4)? (I don't do a lot of animation, so apologies if I've missed something subtle.)</s> *Never mind, you never said #overlay was the image, that was an invalid assumption on my part.*

Comment: There's an even shorter way, `.fadeOut()` sets `display: none` at the end, so `$("#imagecontainer").add(this).fadeOut()` should work. +1 for the issue, would +2 for the bug filing if I could.

Comment: @Nick: Good point about reordering being a more efficient way to fix it. And thanks. :-) I was pulling my hair out earlier today when I ran into this.

Comment: J. - I'd say at this point it was intentional, since `.add(selector, context)` was added when this broke...so it'll probably be closed as not a bug

Comment: @Nick: Just being tidy, I've trimmed my part of our chatter above. :-)